# Unity start function after set a Gameobject active

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want a function like Start() (So it only calls it once)
after I set my GameObject active. How can I do this?

Thought doing it within the Update with an if statement so if GameObject is active it will be called. But the problem is it will call it not once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OnEnable()` method as it is only called once when the object is enabled:

```
void OnEnable()
{
    //This will be called when object is enabled.
    Debug.Log("OnEnabled()", gameObject);
}
```

Update:

[OnEnable()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnEnable.html) is just another Unity method like Start() but its called every time the object activates. 
watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPiHgMIqj2E

Comment: Hmmm... doesn´t work for me? Maybe because I built on Android?

Comment: I have the script with the OnEnable() on the GameObject that will be set active, thats right isnt it?

Comment: Found my mistake I made it IEnumerator. Made it void and started a coroutine there and it works!